# How do I embed external content in mobile website?

Tags: jquery, html, jquery-mobile, html5-video

I am developing a mobile application and I want to use other websites in my mobile web page. However I cannot control the iframe as it automatically increases its width and height.

How do I control the iframe or is there any alternative solution to include other websites in my mobile webpage?

Comment: hey whether you could do the external web page embed in your mobile web page

Comment: I have embeded  external web page  using iframe tag in my jquery mobile page but the size of the iframe does not match  to the height and width which i have given using css property

Answer (score 0):

iFrame Supports following **JS Properties**,

1. align
2. contentDocument
3. contentWindow
4. frameBorder
5. height
6. longDesc
7. marginHeight
8. marginWidth
9. name
10. noResize
11. scrolling
12. src
13. width

You can Set these Values via JS. To Set Fixed Height and Width, CSS is Enough.

**Check this Link**

http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/dom_obj_frame.asp